# Preamble works in .tex file but not in .sty file

Tags: packages, luatex, preamble

I have a question concerning `.sty` files. I often use the same preamble in my latex documents and so I wanted to put it into a `.sty` file. I started with the first few lines, but it already does not work, and i don't know why. 
I apologize in advance should there be a totally obvious mistake in my code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{preamble_article}[Custom Preamble for Articles!]

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=.92}
\setmainfont[
ItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-Italic.otf,
BoldFont=LucidaBrightOT-Demi.otf,
BoldItalicFont=LucidaBrightOT-DemiItalic.otf,
]{LucidaBrightOT.otf}
\setsansfont[
ItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-Italic.otf,
BoldFont=LucidaSansOT-Demi.otf,
BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansOT-DemiItalic.otf,
]{LucidaSansOT.otf}
\setmonofont[
ItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Oblique.otf,
BoldFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-Bold.otf,
BoldItalicFont=LucidaSansTypewriterOT-BoldOblique.otf,
]{LucidaSansTypewriterOT.otf}
\setmathfont{LucidaBrightMathOT.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\newfontface\LucidaBlackletter{LucidaBlackletterOT.otf}
\newfontface\LucidaCalligraphy{LucidaCalligraphyOT.otf}
\newfontface\LucidaHandwriting{LucidaHandwritingOT.otf} 

\endinput
```

If I use the exact same code as a normal preamble (using `\usepackage` instead of `\RequirePackage`) everything works fine. But with this `.sty` file I get the error "Missing number! Treated as zero."
Where is my mistake? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: remove `[Custom Preamble for Articles!]` if that optional argument is used, it must start with a latex-style date

Comment: thanks a lot :D I thought that part was just some kind of package description. thank you

Comment: also some advice – it is better to use `-` than to use `_`.

Comment: @SeanAllred why?

Comment: @daleif as well as being harder to type, the underscore has special meaning in most contexts. It's best to form unilateral habits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove (or fix)

```
[Custom Preamble for Articles!]
```

if that optional argument is used, it must start with a latex-style date, such as

```
 [2015/08/23 v1.0 Custom Preamble for Articles!]
```

Comment: To make it more clear, the format of the date is `YYYY/MM/DD`, a `printf` format string is `%04d/%02d/%02d`. The date is parsed by some LaTeX macros for comparisons (`\@ifpackagelater`, or when `\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage` require a minimum package date (optional argument after the package date).